# Autodesk Forge - Data Transformation error

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When trying to convert an obj file that we have uploaded to a Bucket, then try to run a translation - we get this error:

```
Tr worker fail to download
```

It is sending the POST Job, however that's the error whenever we try to pull the data to render in a viewer.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: we may need a demo OBJ file to diagnose what happened. Or could you share the urn.? We can try to check backend log if it tells some more information

Comment: Can you please double-check the file got uploaded to the bucket correctly? You can use a utility like https://oss-manager.autodesk.io/